# How can I fix a broken Eclipse installation in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, eclipse

It is a shot in the dark, but I have tried everything to reinstall Eclipse.  I did the normal `apt-get install` for Eclipse.

I used it for a year.  And then I decided I wanted to select the *"Upgrade Option"* from the Eclipse Help menu.  After 30 minutes of many downloads, I restarted Eclipse and none of the perspectives worked.  Essentially, when I tried to upgrade through Eclipse, nothing worked afterwards.

I did the `apt-get autoremove` and many ways to remove from Eclipse.

I tried to remove eclipse through apt and also removed some /lib files.  But everytime I install I end up at the same place, Eclipse just won't work.  I am sure there are residual files out there, I just don't know where.

...

When I download Eclipse from the site, it works fine.  I am OK with working this way but I thought I would ask if there is a way to fix the eclipse configuration that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: try sudo apt-get purge eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try `sudo apt-get purge eclipse` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get clean`, and `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Then, try reinstalling Eclipse.

If this doesn't work, move on to the directions below:

Eclipse files are also stored in a per-user directory in one's home folder, namely `.eclipse`, as well as the workspace folder you select at Eclipse startup(unless you set it to never ask you again). You can try renaming these folders in order to reset Eclipse.

Open your home folder, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden files. Find `.eclipse` and rename it to `.eclipseOld`. You can also rename your workspace folder in the same way.

Then, reinstall Eclipse via apt (`sudo apt-get install eclipse`) and try using it again.

Comment: Thanks, that may do it.  I will absorb your comment and do a little research before actually going through with it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I never meet anybody using Eclipse's Ubuntu's packages. And I don't think it is made for being used this way. My boss often told me that he don't care which OS he runs while working under Eclipse because anyway his *main OS was Eclipse and SVN* and it changes nothing for him to use it under Windows or Ubuntu or anything else. I think he is right.

Dealing with Eclipse configurations files and workspaces is tricky : handle with care !

Comment: True, I like the ability to do "apt-get install eclipse"  or apt-get install eclipse-cdt and some other various plugins.  I just like having it as part of the default setup.  I have done 100% of my software installs that way.